# How to delete several lines containing only whitespaces in nano?

Tags: bash, nano

I have been using nano to write a bash script and I am at several times indenting various lines at once with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>}</kbd>. The problem is that the following occurs:

[image]

Several lines without text in them get white-spaces by the amount that I indent the text and they are coloured green. They don't affect the program but they make it look bad. I have been deleting them one by one but it gets frustrating over time. Is there a way to get rid of all the white-spaces at once? maybe some way to select the text (short cut for selecting text in nano is <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd>) and have a short cut do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use global search and replace with the expression `^\s+$`.

1. Switch to search and replace mode with `C-\`.
2. Switch to regex mode with `Alt-R`.
3. Type the expression `^\s+$`.
4. Hit Enter to replace with an empty string.
5. On the match, hit `A` for All.

Comment: Note that it seems that there is no way to match a newline using nano's regex. As such, this answer deletes the _contents_ of lines with whitespace, but it does not delete the lines themselves. (This answer matches what the OP wanted, but not the title of the question.)